# Datetime change error in Automation anywhere

Tags: datetime, bots, automationanywhere

I'm trying to convert the date format from yyyy/MM/dd to dd/MM/yyyy. The year and month are getting changed without error but the value of date is different, like if the original date is 1992/12/02, it is getting converted as 334/12/1992. Any insight on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import datetime
sample_date = "1992/12/02"
sample_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sample_date, "%Y/%m/%d").strftime("%Y/%d/%m")
print(sample_date)
```

Output:

```
1992/02/12
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I'm actually taking data input from a row in excel file and need to append the excel file with the converted dates in another row. Also, I can't use python and just the other commands in automation anywhere.